# Apktool shows error on OS X

Tags: java, android, apk, extract, apktool

Apktool runs but shows an error now .Please help 
Image link attached

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Are you even in the right folder when trying to execute the script?

Comment: Yes, I navigated to the Desktop where I had created the folder containing the files

Comment: Have you set the script to be executable?

Comment: I don't know how to do that.Help please

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about **running a reverse engineering** tool, not about a **specific programming issue**.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have JDK, JRE and Android SDK Installed.
Check out this [link](http://ilikekillnerds.com/2014/09/how-to-decompile-and-compile-android-apks-on-a-mac-using-apktool/), that should help you

Regards.

Comment: All three are installed on the system.According to the link,I enabled root mode and then typed the command but terminal shows sh: apktool: command not found.

Comment: Check whether the path variable is set

you can run `echo $PATH` to check if it is set

Comment: When I ran the command ,it showed /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

Comment: Don't know what to do with the result as I don't know much about terminal commands

Comment: Well, its correctly set though, you can check these links

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XbvyqpnP1-E


http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/install/

Comment: Thanks ,that video helped but terminal starts to decompile it shows an error

Comment: I've attached the error link.Please look into it and help me

Comment: You must have to download `apktoo_2.0.0rc` file. then after You can decompile your apk file and will not get arcs file error.

You can download latest file version from [Here](https://bitbucket.org/iBotPeaches/apktool/downloads)

Now Rename your "apktool_2.0.0rc4.jar" to "apktool.jar".

Now delete old "apktool.jar" file from your apktool folder.

Now put this new "apktool.jar" file in your apktool folder where old "apktool.jar" was placed.

now same run your cmd commands like `apktool if framework-res.apk`

and next

`apktool d "your appname.apk without quotes"`

Answer (score 0):

An online version of the apktool is available here: [www.javadecompilers.com/apktool](http://www.javadecompilers.com/apktool)

Hope, it would help you to decompile the application without installation of the numerous prerequisites.